# How to setup vue template with django project

Tags: django, vue.js

I have downloaded vuejs template,I want to setup with django project(my django side is already up and running) I don't want to spend much time reading the structure of vuejs and its components by now. Am wondering is there any easy way to setup like vue CLI or any. Please help me any easy way to integrate!!

Answer (score 0):

I have came to realize that when configuring template you need to read the template files well in order to have a picture of which file should placed where, and what should be edited, then template will work.At the time of asking this question I was wondering is there any plug in play option for making my downloaded template work, then I did not find anything where I had to read the files in downloaded template folder and analyse them well